# how to get checked value from radiobutton represented as variable?

Tags: jquery

I would like to get checked value of some radiubutton.
That is not a problem when you using expression:

```
 $("input[name='radioname']:checked").val();
```

but I have a situation when I need to use DOM object from variable as below:

```
var obj = $("[name=myradio1]");
```

and now I'm operating with variable obj.

Please explain how to get a checked value from **obj** variable

this is html code:

```
<input id="answer_21" type="radio" value="21" name="answer[1]">
<input id="answer_22" type="radio" value="22" name="answer[1]">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright... this works, I don't know can it be written better, probably can...

```
if (obj.is(':checked')){

        for (a=0; a<obj.length; a++)
            {
            if(obj[a].attributes[3].ownerElement.checked)
                {
                console.log(obj[a].attributes[3].ownerElement.defaultValue)  ;
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

```
if (obj.is(':checked')){
  var val = obj.val();
}
```

---

> Please explain how to get a checked value from obj variable

You can use `is()` and `:checked` filter selector like this:

```
var isChecked = obj.is(':checked');
```

Comment: but I need to know which one is checked, I need a value of checked radio button

Comment: nope... its always returning a first value in collection, mo matter which one radio is checked